# Why is my code found even after I moved it to a subfolder?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, shared-directory, file-structure, resharper-10.0

I embarked upon a refactoring of the file structure of my app, as it has various clearly-defined sections, and putting them in various folders would make the whole thing more grokkable/maintainable.

I thought I was going to run into problems when I created folders in Visual Studio, moved *.cs files into them, and then tried to compile. But no, VS didn't so much as peep, and it ran fine.

To be more specific, I created a folder below my project named "SharedCode" I then dragged a file named SQLDBHelper.cs into that folder (I didn't copy it, I moved it). I thought the references to the code in it, such as:

```
DataTable dtPriceComplianceResults = SQLDBHelper.ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable(ReportRunnerConstsAndUtils.SUMMARY_STOREDPROC, . . .
```

...were going to stop working, since they formerly found that file on the same level (directly below the Project, "ReportRunner") and now it's in "ReportRunner\SharedCode"

But it took the move in stride - compiled, and successfully made the call when I ran the app.

I was also kind of expecting that Visual Studio (or Resharper?) would change this, in SQLDBHelper:

```
namespace ReportRunner
```

...to this:

```
namespace ReportRunner.SharedCode
```

...but it didn't. Why did this work seamlessly, and does it mean that I can create other project folders and drag files into their willy-nilly and expect all the code to still know where to look to find code it calls?

### UPDATE

Although it compiles and runs fine, when I let the Resharper hounds loose on it (via Resharper > Inspect > Code Issues in Solution), I get some fingerwags along these lines:

```
Project ReportRunner
  PriceCompliance\PriceComplianceRpt.cs:13 Namespace does not correspond to file location, should be: 'ReportRunner.PriceCompliance'
```

If I acquiesce, and let Resharper "fix the problem," the namespace changes from "*namespace ReportRunner*" to "*namespace ReportRunner.PriceCompliance*"

But since all works fine without this change resharpening of the namespace, what benefit does appending the folder name to the namespace have?

Comment: Visual Studio won't change the namespace if you move a file. That's something ReSharper should do though. Is your code under source control? Also where did you drag the files - in Visual Studio or just in Windows Explorer?

Comment: Skydrive is my source control. I dragged from within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace and the folder in which classes in that namespace reside don't *have* to have match. There's nothing in C# or .NET that would enforce this. You can call your namespace `A.Really.Long.Name.With.Lots.Of.Dots` and put the classes in a folder called `code` for all that the compiler cares. It's a computer, computers are good at keeping track of things regardless of what they are called.

It is, however, good practice to organise your folders so they match the namespaces (or vice versa) because it makes it easier for *you* (the human being) to find the classes/files you're looking for. You'd struggle to remember where the code was in my (admittedly extreme) example, but in your case all the classes in `ReportRunner.PriceCompliance` will be in a folder called `..\ReportRunner\PriceCompliance` and not somewhere else on the hard drive.

So what ReSharper is doing here is enforcing good practice - which is what it's rather good at.